# Do hydroxymethyl-substituted cyclopropylmethyl cations undergo ring expansion?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

In the image, what would happen after step 2?

1. Will a double bond be formed between carbon 3 and 4? If this is the case, then we would get benzene in the end.
2. But, if the positive charge in shifted to carbon 1, then won't it be a more stable carbocation?
3. Also, if a double bond were to be formed between carbon 1 and 4 now, it would be more substituted than a double bond between carbon 3 and 4.

In spite of all these factors, the double bond is formed between carbons 3 and 4, and benzene is formed.

Kindly explain how this process takes place.And, please tell me how to name this compound.

Comment: I'm suspicious of making a primary carbocation. It's possible that you would get a concerted shift, but even next to a cyclopropane, that looks bad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following takes place-

[image: not available]

And then H<sub>3</sub>O+ can be assumed to give H+ and H<sub>2</sub>O.
Try it out and you'll get to the product.

If the positive charge is shifted to carbon 1, it would form a more stable alkene since it is more substituted. But after formation of C1-C4 double bond, no further reaction will occur since after expansion + charge will be on a double bonded carbon which would be highly unstable. Since Benzene is more stable than the product which will be formed after shifting of + charge to Carbon 1, and since heat is also applied, there will be enough energy to form more stable benzene and thus the reaction takes place in such a manner.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30687/discussion-on-answer-by-gunjan-chhablani-doubt-on-dehydration-of-alcohols-using).